# Azure.Functions.Cli.Common.CliException: Error uploading archive (BadRequest)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I am not able to publish azure functionapp using CLI tool `azure-functionapp-core-tools` version 3. I am getting the below error -

```
Creating archive for current directory...
> /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.2534/gozip -base-dir "/Users/sibaprasad/works/BCD/TalentReferralFunctionApp" -input-file "/var/folders/lx/36x5q85s79lc2cp1gg5ps7h00000gp/T/tmpMKd4Nb.tmp" -output "/var/folders/lx/36x5q85s79lc2cp1gg5ps7h00000gp/T/tmpVq6XLV.tmp"
Uploading 752.3 KB [##############################################################################]
Creating archive for current directory...
> /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.2534/gozip -base-dir "/Users/sibaprasad/works/BCD/TalentReferralFunctionApp" -input-file "/var/folders/lx/36x5q85s79lc2cp1gg5ps7h00000gp/T/tmpTkz1SB.tmp" -output "/var/folders/lx/36x5q85s79lc2cp1gg5ps7h00000gp/T/tmpu0zXFJ.tmp"
Uploading 752.3 KB [##############################################################################]
Creating archive for current directory...
> /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.2534/gozip -base-dir "/Users/sibaprasad/works/BCD/TalentReferralFunctionApp" -input-file "/var/folders/lx/36x5q85s79lc2cp1gg5ps7h00000gp/T/tmpF3WEPY.tmp" -output "/var/folders/lx/36x5q85s79lc2cp1gg5ps7h00000gp/T/tmpMKPt2x.tmp"
Uploading 752.3 KB [##############################################################################]
Azure.Functions.Cli.Common.CliException: Error uploading archive (BadRequest).
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Helpers.RetryHelper.Retry(Func`1 func, Int32 retryCount, TimeSpan retryDelay, Boolean displayError) in D:\a\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Helpers\RetryHelper.cs:line 29
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.PublishZipDeploy(Site functionApp, Func`1 zipFileFactory) in D:\a\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 680
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.PublishRunFromPackageLocal(Site functionApp, Func`1 zipFileFactory) in D:\a\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 500
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.HandleLinuxDedicatedPublish(Site functionApp, Func`1 zipStreamFactory) in D:\a\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 405
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.PublishFunctionApp(Site functionApp, GitIgnoreParser ignoreParser, IDictionary`2 additionalAppSettings) in D:\a\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 313
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.RunAsync() in D:\a\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 173
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.ConsoleApp.RunAsync[T](String[] args, IContainer container) in D:\a\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\ConsoleApp.cs:line 66
```

Comment: What the publish command did you use?

Comment: `func azure functionapp publish <Function App Name>`

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurred occasionally.

You can try to publish a python v2 function with the follow command: `func azure functionapp publish app-name --build-native-deps --no-bundler`.

Or you can delete the function app, app service plan, and associated storage account and starting over from scratch to get around this problem.

Comment: I have created the functionapp in Node JS. So `--build-native-deps --no-bundler` is not neeeded for Node JS.